# ggplot2 in R: How to change starting / ending point for date axis?

Tags: r, date, xts

I am trying to recreate the following plot.

[image]

But no matter what I do, my X-axis marks are starting from 1965 instead of 1963. Here is the graph plot I obtain.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(dulles, aes(Index, Passengers)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(color = "red") + 
  ylim(0, 25000) + 
  scale_x_date(limits = as.Date(c("1963", "2015"), format = "%Y"), date_breaks = "5 years", date_labels = "%Y")
```

As you can see, I have set the limits argument, but they're not being displayed.

I also tried replacing `date_breaks = "5 years", date_labels = "%Y")` with `breaks = as.Date(as.character(seq(1963, 2015, 5)), format = "%Y")` which was probably stupid anyway.

I want the X-axis labels to begin from 1963 and end in 2013 but without removing the data points for 2014 and 2015, just like in the original plot.

How can I do it?

Comment: Post data, please. Or where to find data set `dulles`.

Comment: @RuiBarradas here is the link: https://gofile.io/d/nr01t2

And here is the code I used to load the data into R:
`dulles <- read_excel("./Dulles_2-2.xlsx")
dulles <- as.xts(dulles[,-1], order.by = as.Date(dulles$Year,format = "%Y"))`

Answer (score 2):

To define a breaks vector is a simple way to enforce axis tick marks.

```
library(ggplot2)

breaks.vec <- seq(min(df1$Index), max(df1$Index), by = "5 years")

ggplot(df1, aes(Index, Y)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  geom_point(color = "red") + 
  scale_x_date(breaks = breaks.vec, date_labels = "%Y")
```

[image]

**Test data creation code**

```
set.seed(2021)
Index <- seq(as.Date("1963-01-01"), as.Date("2015-12-31"), by = "1 years")
Y <- cumsum(rnorm(length(Index)))
df1 <- data.frame(Index, Y)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That totally worked. `scale_x_date(name = "Year", date_labels = "%Y", breaks = seq(min(index(dulles)), max(index(dulles)), by = "5 years"))` is the new code I used.